# Can Azure Data Catalog's Rest API be used to upload the data to be anaylzed?

Tags: azure-data-catalog

When I check official documentation, I understood that I need to prepare the metadata about a data source and then I can upload this information to data catalog using the rest API. When I use the web interface however, I can upload documents to be analzed by the Azure Data catalog itself. Is it possible to use the REST API in the same manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The REST API doesn't do any analysis. I believe only the client does that.

Comment: could you please suggest me a way to access the material you linked for data governance question? I'm very interested in that material, unfortunatelly your answer was removed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61740406/data-governance-solution-for-databricks-synapse-and-adls-gen2